# QGraphicsScene set item scene position

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I have a QGraphicsScene that contains a hierarchy of QGraphicsItems. 
Method item.scenePos() returns the scene coordinates of the item. 
I'm looking for something like setScenePos() in order to change positions of the items by giving them scene coordinates. 
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#scenePos) says:

> **QPointF QGraphicsItem::scenePos() const**
>
> Returns the item's position in scene coordinates. This is equivalent to calling mapToScene(0, 0).

to get what you want you can do the inverse

```
# setScenePos(QPointF point)
point = QPointF(xx, yy)
point_item = item.mapFromScene(point)
item.setPos(point_item)
```

Comment: Inside the scene I have an hierarchy of the items. The item that I want to changes is at the bottom of this hierarchy (scene->parent->parent->item). I applied the same approach:

point = item.mapFromScene(point_from_scene)
item.setPos(point)

The position of the item has changed, but  it has wrong position. The new position doesn't match with the real coordinates that I gave. 
Can hierarchy influence on this ?

Comment: @EugeniuZnagovan it could be, I have not tested it with a hierarchy since the position of an item is with respect to the parent, you could provide a [mcve] of your problem to be able to test my code.

Comment: @EugeniuZnagovan May be, you should better `point = item.parentItem().mapFromScene(point_from_scene); item.setPos(point);`. The local coordinate system of the item is its parent, isn't it.